# Using an external barcode scanner with a Delphi 10.3 Rio Firemonkey Android app

Tags: android, delphi, bluetooth, firemonkey, barcode-scanner

There are a few questions about using a barcode scanner with *Delphi* in SO, and if this was a *VCL Windows* application there would be no drama, but none of the answers seem to work for me. This is also about using an external scanner and not using the devices camera to scan barcodes, as that is also a doddle.

In a *VCL* app where I couldn't ensure which control has the focus, I would capture all the keys in `KeyPreview`, and on getting a **CR**, take the preceding value and check to see if it matches a product barcode.

Unfortunately, *Firemonkey* forms have no `KeyPreview` and I can't use the `KeyDown` event of the FMX form, as it has several controls capable of receiving text input, and if any of them have the focus, the event doesn't fire for the form.

These problems are all based on the scanner being paired as a HID, but as an option on the *Motorola CS3070 Bluetooth scanner* I am using, there is also a **Serial Port Profile** mode. It still pairs with the tablet, but not as a keyboard.

But there doesn't seem to be anything in the *Android UI* to indicate what "serial ports" the tablet has, and even if it did, I don't really have any idea on how to connect to and "listen" to that port inside a *Delphi Firemonkey* app.

As others have indicated, serial ports in *Android* are a different beast to *Windows*, and it looks like *Delphi 10.3 Rio* has no native support for using them.

What other options are there?

EDIT:

Looking at the *Zebra* website, which sell a re-branded *CS3070*, there is an *Android SDK* for their scanners, although sadly not for the *CS3070* but they do have one for the *CS4070*. In the documentation they talk about connecting using **BlueTooth** or **SNAPI** (which I believe is the USB/serial mode), and also about subscribing to the scanner events.

Is this something we can do from *FireMonkey* without an SDK?

Comment: Does ``TApdComPort`` from Async Professional  package (downloadable via GetIt) work on Android?

Comment: @DelphiCoder. I will take a look tomorrow and see if it can work, although it seems that supporting a HID scanner is the requirement going forward.

Answer (score 0):

most of barcode reader in android has an SDK driver and send data via a Broadcast intent.
you should check in settings form if there's some info about it or inside the SDK. You just need the activity and category name and some extra info inside intent.

Comment: just for example , in my case, Zebra generates a broadcast with something similar to action = "com.symbol.datawedge.decode" and extra "com.symbol.datawedge.data_string" ;
datalogic : com.datalogic.decodewedge.decode_action  ,   speedata : "com.se4500.onDecodeComplete"
Etc